# How to copy information from a row to multiple rows below it?

Tags: python, dataframe

Original dataframe:

```py
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6   
(1st empty row)   
(2nd empty row)   
...  
(24th empty row)   
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6   
(1st empty row)  
(2nd empty row)  
...  
(24th empty row)
```

New dataframe:

```py
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6  
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6  
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6  
...  
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6  
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6  
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6  
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6  
...  
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6
```

The question is: How to perform the transformation above? Thanks a lot.

Comment: try [df.ffill()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [df.ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), which is

> Synonym for `DataFrame.fillna()` with `method='ffill'`

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6'],
                        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
                        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
                        ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6'],
                        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
                        [None, None, None, None, None, None]
                        ])
print(df)
#       0     1     2     3     4     5
# 0    a1    a2    a3    a4    a5    a6
# 1  None  None  None  None  None  None
# 2  None  None  None  None  None  None
# 3    b1    b2    b3    b4    b5    b6
# 4  None  None  None  None  None  None
# 5  None  None  None  None  None  None

print(df.ffill())
#     0   1   2   3   4   5
# 0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
# 1  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
# 2  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
# 3  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6
# 4  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6
# 5  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the forward fill `method` argument with the DataFrame's `fillna` method:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```